# how can i place two callback functions in a .load() function in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm having issues figuring out how to handle error on my page using .load() function, i already used the call back function for transitioning and i don't  know how or to place the error code and make it work correctly....

i av this code.....

```
$('.menuLink:eq(0)').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    setTimeout($('#navigation ul li').removeClass('expand', 'normal'), 1000);
    $('section').hide().load('index.html section', function() {
        $(this).fadeIn('slow');
    });
});
```

I'll like to load any error that may occur in the section tag...

Comment: Error from where exactly?

Comment: Why can't you just do error checking in the same callback?

Comment: You are french right?

Comment: I'm new to javascript/jquery... when i tried doing the error check on the same callback, it ended up appearing directly in the body instead of inside the section tag where index.html was loaded...

Comment: @AD7six I'm interested in English variations... I just think this "flavour" of English is from a French speaker. I was hoping to edit  the question accordingly

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `load()` you can do the error checking in the same callback function. For example, as given in the [JQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/load/):

**Display a notice if the Ajax request encounters an error.**

```
<script>
$( "#success" ).load( "/not-here.php", function( response, status, xhr ) {
  if ( status == "error" ) {
    var msg = "Sorry but there was an error: ";
    $( "#error" ).html( msg + xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText );
  }
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

In that callback function, first check for errors. Then, if there are no errors, do the fadeIn.

```
$('.menuLink:eq(0)').click(function(event) {
event.preventDefault();
setTimeout($('#navigation ul li').removeClass('expand', 'normal'), 1000);
$('section').hide().load('index.html section', function() {
    // Check for errors here
    $(this).fadeIn('slow');
});
```

});

Comment: `// Check for errors here` <- that's not very helpful

Comment: I thought he was asking where to check for errors, not how. My mistake.

Comment: Thanks a lot, its working fine now...just needed to style the error message for it to appear in the right place....